# change the inside of a loop without testing

Tags: c++, loops

let's say I have the following loops:

```
for(int i=left; i < right; i++) {
    for(int j=top; j < bottom; j++) {
        if(tilesMap[i][j])
            (tilesMap[i][j])->Draw(window) ;
    }
}
```

and

```
for(int i=left; i < right; i++) {
    for(int j=top; j < bottom; j++) {
        (tilesMap[i][j])->Draw(window) ;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make this "generic", ie if some boolean is true, I will call the first code segment, if not I'll call the second code segment.
I obviously could do a test before the loop and branch on the right loop, but then I have to duplicate the loop "header" and the instruction inside too, and change it twice every time I change the code inside the loop. The other solution is to do a test inside the lopp at every iteration, but this would make way too many tests at runtime.
Is there any other way I can do this? thanks

EDIT: this is just a question for my knowledge, I'm perfectly fine with duplicating my code for such small amount

Comment: Well, why not just make one loop and add condition inside?

Comment: You've already figured out one way.  Why do you want another?  In other words...  huh?

Comment: There are certainly some fancy tricks you could do to write the code once and have it take the correct path inside, but this is one of those situations where I have to question your desire to nitpick such a small performance detail. The top code block looks fine. You should just use it. Have you profiled your code? Is this really a bottleneck? I will post a possible solution if you REALLY need it.

Comment: if I put a condition like if(condition && tilesMap[i][j]) then it'll be tested at each iteration of the loop

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw thanks, but this just a theoretical question, I am indeed fine with duplicating the code, it's just that I was wondering if there was a solution without doing so

Comment: Computers are smarter than you give them credit for... such a repeated test that consistently succeeds/fails will be largely free, especially relative to what is almost certainly an expensive `Draw` operation afterwards.

Comment: @John Dibling I just find it dumb to test each time for a condition when it won't change at each iteration. Obviously the time taken by this is neglible, but it's a theoretical question

Comment: "clever" is frequently the enemy of "readable" and "maintainable."  Any clever solution will require more code, likely elsewhere in your program away from the call site.  Choose your battles wisely.

Comment: Consider that the explicit tests might be easier for a human being to understand in 3 years when some poor schmuck has to maintain your "clever" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pointer to a function(i,j).

Or an object. If you use C++, you can do it object oriented way i.e. with a virtual method and inheritance. It will need a lot of source lines, but it will be clean code. :-)

Comment: _Calling a virtual function_ is slower than _Testing a boolean variable_, isn't it?

Comment: To OP:  You've accepted this as The Answer.  Does this mean you're going to introduce function pointers or polymorphism as a means to make your code pretty or clever?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this code is small enough to just duplicate the loop. I'd be okay with a tiny bit of code-duplication if it makes it more readable and helps performance.

I would say that putting a test inside the loop could make it harder to read since it increases the nesting depth.

Answer (score 1):

Branch predictors work quite well.

That said, you could wrap your two loop bodies in strategy objects, run the test outside of the loop once to choose one, and have the loop body delegate to the strategy method.